Ms Access Updating bound Form via combo box
I have a form with several text fields, combo boxes and even a tab control. Everything is bound to a dataset. On selection of the combobox which has unique contents I would like all the controls to change accordingly. I've kinda done it, but I feel it was too complicated..I basically went through all the controls and set it like this:
For each ctrl in me.controls
For i=0 to rs dields.count-1
  If ctrl.name = rs.fields(i).name then
Ctrl.value = rs.fields(i).value
Exit for
Next i 

Next ctrl
Rs.close



It kinda works, but the navigation panel(?) with the arrows at the bottom of the row doesn't show the correct row, and I was thinking, there should be a better way to do this, if I had the row..
So I want to actually match the ID of the selected combos with the row in the data set, and simply give this row number information(ID) to the form for everything to update automatically.
Thanks in advance

You can remove the inner loop: on error resume next : For each ctrl in me.controls : Ctrl.value = rs(ctrl.name) : Next 

If you want the complete recordsource to remain there :
Call DoCmd.GoToRecord(acDataForm, Me.Form.Name, acGoTo, Me.myComboBox)

The value that you choose in the comboxbox is then the offset value where you want the record to jump to.
To link this in the form, you can add the query bellow as a recordsource of the form :
SELECT tblTea.Id, tblTea.TeaCD, tblTea.Tea_Name, DCount("[ID]","[tblTea]","[ID]<=" & [ID]) AS row_id
FROM tblTea
ORDER BY tblTea.Id;

The row id will give you the nr represented in the recordset.
Here is an example of the data :

As you can see , i deleted id 5.
Yet the total nr of records are 5, butt the highest id is 6.

This shows a combobox with all the relevant data, based on the query as described above. The first column of the combobox is hidden and contains the row_id value. So if you choose tea id : 6 it will jump to record 5 in your form.
This is the recorsource of the combobox
SELECT qfrmTea.row_id, qfrmTea.Id FROM qfrmTea ORDER BY qfrmTea.row_id; 


No. I  still want the recordsource to have the 35 datasets, say, but be "pointing" at a particular dataset, which I would like to choose via the combo box instead of the arrows at the bottom.

You know what I mean?

Hello Kingsley, Did you try the above ? This should work.

Yes, I have.. Unfortunately, I get a 2498 error saying that I used the wrong data type for one of the parameters.  I have me.cboName instead of your me.mucombobox.. I also checked, it is definately a string.

There is something missing.. There is no connection between the data in column Name from cboName and the ID of the table bound

The value that you insert into the me.myCombobox value is the value that you would insert in the arrows at the bottom. There is indeed no link with the ID of the field. Therefore you should set the recordsource of the form. Lets say you have 35 records, when you select nr 10 in the myComboBox, the recordset will go to record nr 10 without caring about the ID of the record. You can add a rowNr to your query and attatch this to the combobox, this way you will have the correct nr in the recordset.

@Matthias X, I was just looking at the rest of your solution. So the combo box has to have a different recordsource? I was hoping that the combo box being bound to the form would also work as a normal field of the dataset. Basically, the user is to have a choice of using the arrows OR selecting the dataset of the bound table via the combo box.

The recordsource is different because you need the link between the row nr and the id of the record. You can add the Row_ID as a Controlsource for the combobox,when the user uses the arrows, it will move allong.
